# dynamic_cast returns std::bad_cast and I don't know why

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a base class and a derived class, and I have a line that gives me the error std::bad_cast if base is an object of the base class. Why does it give me that error? And trying I have seen that static_cast works, but I don't know why.

The line is:

```
#include <iostream>
  class Base
  {
   public:
     virtual void g(){std::cout<<"a";};
   };

  class Derived: public Base
 {
  public:
   void g(){std::cout<<"b";};
  };

  void fn(Base & base) 
  { 

    Derived & pb = dynamic_cast<Derived &>(base); 

     pb.g(); 

   } 

  int main() 
   { 
     Base f1;
    fn(f1);
   }
```

Comment: Never tried to cast something to a reference before. Neat. Learned something.

Comment: @Kevin It is a exercise I am doing by myself to try different things with inheritance and casting, so it doesn´t have a lot of sense

Comment: `Base` is not a `Derived`. This should fail.

Comment: `static_cast` doesn't exactly "work". It simply has undefined behavior.

Comment: *base is a object of the base class, why does it give me that error?* -- Look at your code.  You're telling the system that the type passed is a `Derived` and `dynamic_cast` reported the "lie" by throwing the exception.

Comment: The entire purpose of `dynamic_cast` is to ensure that casts like this fail. If you didn't want to avoid casting an object to something it's not, you don't need a dynamic cast.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to cast a `Base&` that is actually a `Base&` (not a `Derived&`) to a `Derived&` so of course it's going to fail. Remember, all `Derived` objects are also `Base` objects, but not all `Base` objects are `Derived` objects.

What you probably want to do is pass an actual `Derived` object to the function

```
int main()
{
    Derived f1;
    fn(f1);
}
```

Let me explain with a more concrete example.

```
struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(int width, int height):
        width(width), height(height) {}
    virtual ~Rectangle() {}
    int width, height;
};
struct Square: Rectangle
{
    Square(int size): Rectangle(size, size) {}
};

int main()
{
    Square square(3);
    Rectangle rect(1, 2);

    Rectangle& ref_to_square = square;
    Rectangle& ref_to_rect   = rect;

    // This is okay
    // ref_to_square is a reference to an actual square
    dynamic_cast<Square&>(ref_to_square);

    // This will fail
    // ref_to_rect is *not* a reference to an actual square
    dynamic_cast<Square&>(ref_to_rect);
}
```

Comment: So it fails because the object casted is "incomplete"?

Comment: No, it fails because the object isn't a `Derived` object, so trying to cast it to one will fail.

Comment: If no instance of `Derived` exists, how can you call the `g` member function of the class `Derived`? What would `this` point tto?